# Why does csvkit's in2csv convert dates to integers?

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I have a .xlsx file downloaded from [this URL](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/interest-rates/files/TCF.xlsx), which contains rows like the following: [image: sample rows]

but when I attempt to convert this file using in2csv, from csvkit version 0.9.1, I get output lines such as:

```
3,,0.625,42185,42916,912828XJ4,1900-01-26,0.9119,-----,...
4,,0.875,41835,42931,912828WT3,1900-01-27,0.9122,-----,...
```

Instead of entries recognizable as dates, we get integers. The integers seem to be the number of days between 1900-01-01 and the corresponding date in the xlsx. Additionally, values that should be integers ($26 and $27) show up in date format! Is there a simple way to get in2csv to output these dates in a format where they are recognizable as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In Short

Just upgrade `openpyxl` package. It's a known bug of it and has been fixed.

```
pip install --upgrade openpyxl
```

After upgrade:

```
3,,0.625,2015-06-30,2017-06-30,912828XJ4,26,0.9119,-----,...
4,,0.875,2014-07-15,2017-07-15,912828WT3,27,0.9122,-----,...
```

## In Long

I copied a typical line of the table into a newly created .xlsx file and got the following error when converting:

```
list index out of range
```

Trace the exception:

```
>>> from csvkit import convert
>>> convert.convert(open('test.xlsx', 'rb'), 'xlsx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/csvkit/convert/__init__.py", line 39, in convert
    return xlsx2csv(f, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/csvkit/convert/xlsx.py", line 51, in xlsx2csv
    book = load_workbook(f, use_iterators=True, data_only=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 154, in load_workbook
    _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, read_only, keep_vba)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 209, in _load_workbook
    parsed_styles = read_style_table(archive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.py", line 200, in read_style_table
    p.parse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.py", line 56, in parse
    self.parse_cell_styles()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.py", line 138, in parse_cell_styles
    self._parse_xfs(node)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.py", line 160, in _parse_xfs
    format_code = self.number_formats[numFmtId-165]
IndexError: list index out of range
list index out of range
```

So things happened in `openpyxl` package, which is used to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files.

The issue has been [reported](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/440/regression-220-failed-to-read-a-xslx-file) and [fixed](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/commits/4b03e80bfa21) in the latest version of `openyxl`. However in `requirements.txt` of `csvkit`:

```
openpyxl==2.2.0-b1
```

According to [this issue](https://github.com/onyxfish/csvkit/issues/391), it's just a workaround back then so I think just upgrade `openpyxl` (currently 2.2.5) and you are good.